# Why adding yeild() cause the unit test to fail?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

How can I test a cooperative function for cancelation with the yeild() method?

I wrote a unit test for this repository and it passed but when I add `yeild()` method to make the `refreshTitle` method cooperative for cancellation then the unit test failed.

```
 suspend fun refreshTitle() {
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        try {
            val result = network.fetchNextTitle()
            //yield()    //by uncommenting this line the unit test fails.
            titleDao.insertTitle(Title(result))
        } catch (cause: Throwable) {
            throw TitleRefreshError("Unable to refresh title", cause)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the unit test:

```
 @Test
fun whenRefreshTitleSuccess_insertsRows() = runBlockingTest() {
    val titleDao = TitleDaoFake("title")
    val subject = TitleRepository(
        network = MainNetworkFake("OK"),
        titleDao = titleDao,
        ioDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher(),
    )
    subject.refreshTitle()
    Truth.assertThat(titleDao.nextInsertedOrNull()).isEqualTo("OK")
}
```

The code comes from this android codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#9

Comment: What is the error message? I think `yield()` generally shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet

Comment: @broot this error appears by only adding `yield()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have to update these libraries to `1.7.1` version:

```
def coroutines_android_version = '1.7.1'
"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_android_version",
"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_android_version",
"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_android_version"
```

To prevent this error I defined `StandardTestDispatcher` with the same `TestCroutineScheduler` as a field called `standardTestDispatcher`.

**Detected use of different schedulers. If you need to use several test coroutine dispatchers, create one `TestCoroutineScheduler` and pass it to each of them.**

and then changed the test function as follows:

```
private val scheduler = TestCoroutineScheduler()
private val standardTestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(scheduler)

@Test
fun whenRefreshTitleSuccess_insertsRows() = runTest(
    context = standardTestDispatcher,
) {
    val titleDao = TitleDaoFake("title")
    val subject = TitleRepository(
        network = MainNetworkFake("OK"),
        titleDao = titleDao,
        ioDispatcher = standardTestDispatcher,
    )
    subject.refreshTitle()
    Truth.assertThat(titleDao.nextInsertedOrNull()).isEqualTo("OK")
}
```

Now I can test the cooperative function for cancellation successfully with `yeild()` method. It works without `yeild()`.

```
suspend fun refreshTitle() {
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        try {
            val result = withTimeout(5_000) {
                network.fetchNextTitle()
            }
            yield()
            titleDao.insertTitle(Title(result))
        } catch (cause: Throwable) {
            throw TitleRefreshError("Unable to refresh title", cause)
        }
    }
}
```